# Check if any of the duplicated class have text equals or higher then 21

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to setup a discount monitor over my e-commerce to check if someone publishes products with wrong discount. My product page have about 30 items and some of them have a little discount label like this:

```
<span class="nf-off-price"><b>20</b>% off!</span>
<span class="nf-off-price"><b>7</b>% off!</span>
<span class="nf-off-price"><b>12</b>% off!</span>
<span class="nf-off-price"><b>5</b>% off!</span>
<span class="nf-off-price"><b>4</b>% off!</span>
<span class="nf-off-price"><b>4</b>% off!</span>
```

I need to check if any of those labels have a 'nf-off-price > b' equals or higher then 21, and if so, issue an chrome alert. I was able to achieve that but only when setting a solid number, like this:

```
if(Notification.permission !== 'granted'){Notification.requestPermission();}

var check = function(){
    if ($('.nf-off-price:contains("21")').length > 0) {
         n = new Notification( "Discount Alert", {
         body: "A possible discount typo was found",
         icon : "http://cloudcheckr.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/alert.jpg"
    });
    }
};
setTimeout(check, 5000); // Do not remove. The code needs to fire 5 seconds after page load
```

I understand that my code will look for a label with exactly 21 and that's the problem. How can I do for the code to check if at least one out of the many ".nf-off-price" on the page contains  equals or higher then 21?

Comment: If it's consistent like in your HTML, get the text in `<b>` and convert it to an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your check function to this:

```
var check = function(){
    $('.nf-off-price b').each(function() {
      if (parseInt(this.innerHTML, 10) > 20) {
         n = new Notification( "Discount Alert", {
             body: "A possible discount typo was found",
             icon : "http://cloudcheckr.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/alert.jpg"
         });
         return;
      }
    })
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works great. The code is giving me more then one notification, probably because there're more then one price above the threshold. Is there a way to limit it to only one notification? I won't need more. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Notification.permission !== 'granted') {
  Notification.requestPermission();
}

var check = function() {
  $('.nf-off-price').each(function() {
    var price = parseFloat($(this).text());
    if (price > 20) {
      n = new Notification("Discount Alert", {
        body: "A possible discount typo was found " + $(this).text(),
        icon: "http://cloudcheckr.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/alert.jpg"
      });
      return false;
    } 
  });

};
setTimeout(check, 5000); // Do not remove. The code needs to fire 5 seconds after page load
```

This will work as long as your format is as you show it.  But, if you put any characters before the number, parseFloat will give you NaN.

https://jsfiddle.net/434vj1v2/1/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works great. The code is giving me more then one notification, probably because there're more then one price above the threshold. Is there a way to limit it to only one notification? I won't need more. Thanks :)

Comment: Sure, just add a 'return false;' after the notification.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
    $(".nf-off-price b").each(value, function() {
        if (parseInt(value) > 21) {
            // trigger alert here
            return // this prevents more than one notification
        }
    }
```

I haven't tested this code but I think it should work

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer. I've tried a few things with your code and it didn't work. Maybe I am doing something wrong?